# IBM COBOL on AIX file access

Tags: file, aix, cobol

We are migrating a bunch of COBOL programs from z/OS to AIX 7. We are using the IBM COBOL Compiler (5.1) on AIX. Now I don't understand how the file access and the file system work for COBOL on AIX.
The COBOL code is straight forward with

```
SELECT  :FILE:    ASSIGN       TO  :FILE:
                              ORGANIZATION IS  SEQUENTIAL
                              ACCESS  MODE IS  SEQUENTIAL
                              STATUS       IS  S-STATUS.
```

and then doing an `OPEN INPUT`

This compiled fine on AIX:

```
PP 5724-Z87 IBM COBOL for AIX  5.1.0 in progress ...
LineID  Message code  Message text
    91  IGYGR1216-I   A "RECORDING MODE" of "F" was assumed for file           
                      "CUSTOMERS".                                              
    94  IGYGR1216-I   A "RECORDING MODE" of "F" was assumed for file           
                      "LIST1".                                              
    97  IGYGR1216-I   A "RECORDING MODE" of "F" was assumed for file "UINPUT". 
Messages    Total    Informational    Warning    Error    Severe    Terminating
Printed:       3           3                                               
End of compilation 1,  program xxxxx,  highest severity: Informational.
```

Now the problem is, that when running the program the file is not found. It gives Status code: 37

I know that I have to provide a file system for the file on the shell (ksh), as such:
`export CUSTOMERS="STL-CUSTOMERS"`. The file is in the same directory as the program.

My question is this: Which file system to use? I tried "STL" which seemed to me like the "standard" AIX file system (which is JFS2). But that doesn't work. The other option are (from the COBOL on AIX Programming Guide 5.1):

- DB2
- SdU (SMARTdata Utilities)
- SFS (Encina Structured File Server)
- STL (standard language)
- QSAM (queued sequential access method)
- RSD (record sequential delimited)

We tried all and the file system that worked was "QSAM". The file is a text file (ASCII), that was transfered from the mainframe. But not directly, it was first copied by FTP and then converted to ASCII on Windows (we had to fix the line breaks). When playing around with it to make it work, we edited the file with vi to make the lines 80 characters each. So it was edited on AIX and looks like a ordinary text file on AIX.
Why would COBOL still want QSAM as "file system"? What does the term "file system" mean here any way? It seems that it is not in the sense of a real file system such as JFS.

Comment: There is a lot of information in the Programmers Guide - too much for me to go through. Have you gone through it?

Comment: Yes, I went through it but could could not make much sense of it. It says for QSAM: "The QSAM (queued sequential access method) file system supports fixed, variable,
and spanned records. Using the QSAM file system, you can directly access a
QSAM file that you transferred from the mainframe to AIX." Not really answering why this would work and STL wouldn't. All of the Programming Guide reads as it about the Mainframe and not a Unix-system such as AIX.

Comment: You did read the Programmers Guide that related to AIX, didn't you? Sounds like you read the zOS version. I googled with 'cobol aix documentation' and it was the first hit that leads to the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I did read the AIX Programmers guide. It does sound like the zOS one, that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see where this would be confusing...  Especially coming from a Non-POSIX environment.

I'll start with the answer, and then provide more information.

For a normal text file, you want RSD, and to make sure that the \n is column 81.
A record length of 80 is **just** the data portion, not including the delimiter.
QSAM (fixed length) would appear to work, but would return the \n as part of the data!

Your FS=37 means that the attributes of the file don't match what the program is asking for (more esoteric than, say, FS=39 - invalid fixed attributes).  In this case, it means the file you wanted to open was not, really, a STL file.

By filesystem we mean how the data is physically stored on the platter, SSD, RAM, ...  More accurately, how we format the record before handing it off to the next lower level of I/O.

There are two basic types of filesystems:

- Native (on top of JFS2, JFS, NFS, CIFS, ...) RSD, QSAM, LSQ, STL, SdU.  These filesystems can be operated on by standard OS utilities
- Non-Native (on top of another product)  DB2 (DB2) and SFS (TxSeries/CICS).  These filesystems are invisible to standard OS utilities

Then, there are groupings by type of COBOL organization (**preferred**):

- Sequential:  All filesystems support Sequential...z/OS:  QSAM, VSAM
- Relative:    **STL**, SdU, **SFS**, DB2...........z/OS:  VSAM
- Indexed:     **STL**, SdU, **SFS**, DB2...........z/OS:  VSAM

Of the Native filesystems, QSAM(variable), STL and SDU contain metadata, making them not really viewable in vi,cat,...  Ok... you can open them in vi, but it will look like utter garbage.

**QSAM** is a faithful implementation of z/OS:

- Fixed length records:  Raw data, no BDW/RDW, no line delimiters (\n).
- Variable length records: RDW + raw data (no \n)...  However there is no BDW.

**RSD** is a normal stream (text) file; each record is terminated with \n, which is **not** counted in the record length (the program will never see them).

**LSQ** (Line Sequential) is the same as on z/OS - messy semantics.

**VSAM** is an alias for a filesystem that provides all the features of z/OS VSAM.
Unfortunately, for historical reasons, it points to SdU...

**STL** is, **by far and away**, better at everything than is SdU.

**SdU** was the first filesystem to cover QSAM and VSAM, but is old and decrepit, compared to STL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does make some things clearer. Coming from a Java and Python background this is really strange. So I put some information on the data structure in the COBOL program but some part of the structure information is in the "filesystem" external to the program?

Comment: I get the confusion..  I am not a COBOL programmer (well since the early '80s... ie before COBOL  78 was widely in the field.).... 

COBOL has one of the richest sets of I/O functions I've seen in 32+ years !

The important part for you, as a programmer is to describe the data layout... The file system you you choose may add additional metadata,  but that *should* be invisible to your program (but maybe visible to you, if you use vi, cat, etc)

Comment: That all said, I **am** L3/dev for COBOL on workstation... So I'll get you an answer :-)